# Asynchronous ngOptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-ng-options

To be honest, I have no idea what I'm doing within Angular, so this is probably terrible coding practices. In any case, I'm trying to load some data into a `<select>` element asynchronously.

Here's the template HTML:

```
<div ng-include src="'scripts/common/toolbar/toolbar.html'"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div ng-include src="'scripts/common/header/pageheader.html'"></div>
    <label>Advertisers:
        <select ng-model="selectedAdvertiser" ng-options="adv as adv.name for adv in advertisers"></select>
    </label>
</div>
```

Here is the controller (template's controller is HomeCtrl from $routeProvider)

```
angular.module('feedsmanagerApp').controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, ngDialog, userService) {
    $scope.advertisers = [];
    userService.getUser().then(function(user) {
        $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
            $scope.advertisers = user.getAdvertisers();
        })
    });
//more stuff down here....
```

The data that gets returned from user.getAdvertisers() looks like this:

`[{name:'aaaa', id:0}, {name:'bbbb', id:1}];`

Lastly, here is the userService

```
var userPromise,

        getUser = function() {
            if(!userPromise) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                userPromise = deferred.promise;
                deferred.resolve(User.createFromServerData(null));
            }
            return userPromise;
        };
```

I've tried using $timeout, $scope.$apply, $scope.$evalAsync...I'm pretty much out of ideas. I can't get any data to show up in the select at all. Any help would be extremely appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking this should work:

```
userService.getUser().then(function(user) {
    $scope.advertisers = user.getAdvertisers();
});
```

Or this if `getAdvertisers` returns a promise:

```
userService.getUser().then(function(user) {
    user.getAdvertisers().then(function (advertisers) {
        $scope.advertisers = advertisers;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey, yeh I tried that as well (your first code-piece). I get an empty option back that looks like this:

`<option value="?" selected="selected" label=""></option>`

Answer (score -1):

Never mind. It was an issue with the way I was retrieving the data. D'oh!

Comment: I think you should post your answer (the fix) for the benefit of others as well?